# Transferring SBEE configuration - Error: Entity of type Dimension does not provide field DimensionLinkDimensionID

Tags: configuration, sbee

We are trying to transfer a SAP Smart Business, executive edition 1.0 1509 (SBEE) configuration from one system to another (Importing and Exporting Dashboard Definitions)

During the Import we get the error message: **The following error occurred: Entity of type Dimension does not provide field DimensionLinkDimensionID**

We did not find the error message using a search engine :/

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this must be a bug with the application. Talk to SAP, it would be fixed ASAP :-)